# Object Oriented programming in python ShoppingCart

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Create a class called ShoppingCart.

Create a constructor that takes no arguments and sets the total attribute to zero, and initializes an empty dict attribute named items.

Create a method add_item that requires item_name, quantity and price arguments.
This method should add the cost of the added items to the current value of total.
It should also add an entry to the items dict such that the key is the item_name
and the value is the quantity of the item.

Create a method remove_item that requires similar arguments as add_item. It should remove items that have been added to the shopping cart and are not required. This method should deduct the cost of the removed items from the current total and also update the items dict accordingly.

If the quantity of an item to be removed exceeds the current quantity of that item in the cart, assume that all entries of that item are to be removed.

Create a method checkout that takes in cash_paid and returns the value of balance from the payment.
If cash_paid is not enough to cover the total, return "Cash paid not enough".

Create a class called Shop that has a constructor which takes no arguments and initializes an attribute called quantity at 100.

Make sure Shop inherits from ShoppingCart.

In the Shop class, override the remove_item method, such that calling Shop's remove_item with no arguments decrements quantity by one'''

Here is my updated code.

```
class ShoppingCart(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.total = 0
    self.items = {}

  def add_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
    self.total = (quantity * price)
    self.items = {item_name : quantity}

  def remove_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
    self.total -= (quantity * price)
    if quantity > self.items[item_name]:
        del self.items
    self.items[item_name] -= quantity

  def checkout(self, cash_paid):
    balance = 0
    if cash_paid < self.total:
      return "Cash paid not enough"
    balance = cash_paid - self.total
    return balance


class Shop(ShoppingCart):

  def __init__(self):
    ShoppingCart.__init__(self)
    self.quantity = 100

  def remove_item(self):
    self.quantity -=1


import unittest

    class ShoppingCartTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            self.cart = ShoppingCart()
            self.shop = Shop()

        def test_cart_property_initialization(self):
            self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 0, msg='Initial value of total not correct')
            self.assertIsInstance(self.cart.items, dict, msg='Items is not a dictionary')

        def test_add_item(self):
            self.cart.add_item('Mango', 3, 10)

            self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 30, msg='Cart total not correct after adding items')
            self.assertEqual(self.cart.items['Mango'], 3, msg='Quantity of items not correct after adding item')

        def test_remove_item(self):
            self.cart.add_item('Mango', 3, 10)
            self.cart.remove_item('Mango', 2, 10)

            self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 10, msg='Cart total not correct after removing item')
            self.assertEqual(self.cart.items['Mango'], 1, msg='Quantity of items not correct after removing item')

        def test_checkout_returns_correct_balance(self):
            self.cart.add_item('Mango', 3, 10)
            self.cart.add_item('Orange', 16, 10)

            self.assertEqual(self.cart.checkout(265), 75, msg='Balance of checkout not correct')
            self.assertEqual(self.cart.checkout(25), 'Cash paid not enough', msg='Balance of checkout not correct')

        def test_shop_is_instance_of_shopping_cart(self):
            self.assertTrue(isinstance(self.shop, ShoppingCart), msg='Shop is not a subclass of ShoppingCart')

        def test_shop_remove_item_method(self):
            for i in range(15):
                self.shop.remove_item()

            self.assertEqual(self.shop.quantity, 85)
```

After running the unittest, the test.checkout_returns_correct_balance fails.
This is the message i got:
    `self.assertEqual(self.cart.checkout(265), 75, msg='Balance of checkout not correct')
    AssertionError: 105 != 75 : Balance of checkout not correct`

I really need some help with this.

Comment: Which tests? What was the expected output? What was the observed output? You can't just dump the homework description and a bunch of code and expect us to start from scratch.

Comment: @ShadowRanger the 'add_item' method and the 'remove_item' method, i didn't implement the right code.. could you just go through it, the code is pretty messy

Comment: Unfortunately, "the code is pretty messy" is a good reason for us *not* to go through your code. We're not getting payed to debug your code, and messy code is no fun to wade through. Perhaps you should clean it up and see if the issue becomes clearer to you? If not, perhaps you'll have narrowed the issue down to something you can turn into a [mcve].

Comment: @Blckknght, i only have issues with `.checkout` method.

Comment: @Blckknght its not messy anymore. i have made changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have in your code is that `add_item` doesn't *add* items to an existing set of items in the cart, it sets your cart's contents to the new item and makes it forget about what it had before. You need to take into account the previous contents of the cart, so it multiple items can be added in separate calls to `add_item`.

Your `remove_item` is much closer to correct, though I think it's a little overzealous in deleting the whole `items` dictionary when all items of the requested type have been removed (it should probably only delete one key with `del self.items[item_name]`, and the `>` should probably be `>=`, or maybe `==` with `>` raising an exception).

Comment: I figured also that the `add_item` does not add new items to the existing cart... But I can't find my way around it...could you help me with that?

Comment: On a basic level, use `+=` instead of `=`. There may need to be some extra logic to handle the `items` dictionary. (Using the `collections.defaultdict` class would make it very simple, but you should also learn how to make it work with a regular dictionary.)

Comment: I did run the test again and it passed but when i try to submit the code on the platform....i get a message that it failed to pass all the test......something like this `KeyError ('Mango',),` what could have caused it and i have tripled checked the code...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
class ShoppingCart(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.total = 0
       self.items = {}

   def add_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
       self.total += price*quantity
       self.items.update({item_name: quantity})

   def remove_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
       if item_name in self.items:
           if quantity < self.items[item_name] and quantity > 0:
               self.items[item_name] -= quantity
               self.total -= price*quantity


       elif quantity >= self.items[item_name]:
           self.total -= price*self.items[item_name]
           del self.items[item_name]


   def checkout (self, cash_paid):
       if cash_paid >= self.total:
           return cash_paid - self.total
       return "Cash paid not enough"

 class Shop(ShoppingCart):

     def __init__(self):
         self.quantity = 100

     def remove_item(self):
         self.quantity -=1
```